# How to determine whether an object has a given property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

How can I determine whether an object `x` has a defined property `y`, regardless of the value of `x.y`?

I'm currently using

```
if (typeof(x.y) !== 'undefined')
```

but that seems a bit clunky. Is there a better way?

Comment: Don't "call" `typeof` with `()`, [it is an operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), not a function

Answer (score 685, accepted):

### Object has property:

If you are testing for properties that are on the object itself (not a part of its prototype chain) you can use [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
if (x.hasOwnProperty('y')) { 
  // ......
}
```

### Object or its prototype has a property:

You can use the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator to test for properties that are inherited as well.

```
if ('y' in x) {
  // ......
}
```

Comment: Or even better — `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'y')`, so that property named "hasOwnProperty" would not conflict with inspection process ;)

Comment: Or even shorter — `{}.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'y')`.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins

Comment: Use [`Object.hasOwn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) these days

Answer (score 89):

If you want to know if the object *physically* contains the property [@gnarf's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894792/determining-if-a-javascript-object-has-a-given-property/1894803#1894803) answer using `hasOwnProperty` will do the work.

If you're want to know if the property exists anywhere, either on the object itself or up in the prototype chain, you can use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/in_Operator).

```
if ('prop' in obj) {
  // ...
}
```

Eg.:

```
var obj = {};

'toString' in obj == true; // inherited from Object.prototype
obj.hasOwnProperty('toString') == false; // doesn't contains it physically
```

Answer (score 16):

Underscore.js or Lodash

```
if (_.has(x, "y")) ...
```

:)

Comment: Nope. It's just an alias for `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, "y")`. For arrays I think you might want `Array.prototype.indexOf`, `_.indexOf`, or `_.contains`

Answer (score 14):

You can trim that up a bit like this:

```
if ( x.y !== undefined ) ...
```

Comment: That would fail with `x = {y:undefined}`

Comment: Does anyone need to distinguish between "not defined" and "defined to be undefined?"

Comment: @darkporter I do sometimes ;)

Comment: @jpsimons for and instance "defined to be undefined" is used by Firestore when saving document data.

Answer (score 6):

One feature of my original code

```
if ( typeof(x.y) != 'undefined' ) ...
```

that might be useful in some situations is that it is safe to use whether `x` exists or not. With either of the methods in gnarf's answer, one should first test for `x` if there is any doubt if it exists.

So perhaps all three methods have a place in one's bag of tricks.

Comment: You could always use `(x && x.hasOwnProperty('y'))` or `(x && 'y' in x)`

Comment: I agree, testing for x should be a separate case on it's own. Also yields better error reporting.

Comment: That failed for me. If x is undefined then typeof(x.y) returns a `ReferenceError` rather than the string 'undefined'

Answer (score 5):

**includes**

```
Object.keys(x).includes('y');
```

The `Array.prototype.includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

and

`Object.keys()` returns an array of strings that represent all the enumerable properties of the given object.

`.hasOwnProperty()` and the ES6+ `?.` -optional-chaining like: `if (x?.y)` are very good 2020+ options as well.

Comment: I would avoid this - `Object.keys(x)` will unnecessarily generate an array containing all keys of `x` - this should be avoidable.

Answer (score 3):

#### ES6+:

There is a new feature on ES6+ that you can check it like below:

```js
if (x?.y)
```

Actually, the interpretor checks the existence of `x` and then call the `y` and because of putting inside `if` parentheses the coercion happens and `x?.y` converted to boolean.

Comment: What if `x.y` exists and it is a *falsy* value.

Comment: @DaniloGómez The compiler first checks If x['y'] exists, if x has a property of ['y'] then the value of ['y'] will invoke where this value is `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers I would like to suggest using the `Object.hasOwn()` method for checking if the specified object has the specified property as its own property (meaning on the object itself) you can use the new `Object.hasOwn()` method which is a static method which returns true if the specified object has the specified property as its own property. If the property is inherited, or does not exist, the method returns false.

```js
const person = { name: 'dan' };

console.log(Object.hasOwn(person, 'name'));// true
console.log(Object.hasOwn(person, 'age'));// false

const person2 = Object.create({gender: 'male'});

console.log(Object.hasOwn(person2, 'gender'));// false
```

It is recommended to this method use over the `Object.hasOwnProperty()` because it also works for objects created by using `Object.create(null)` and for objects that have overridden the inherited `hasOwnProperty()` method. Although it's possible to solve these kind of problems by calling `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` on an external object, `Object.hasOwn()`  overcome these problems, hence is preferred (see examples below)

```js
let person = {
  hasOwnProperty: function() {
    return false;
  },
  age: 35
};

if (Object.hasOwn(person, 'age')) {
  console.log(person.age); // true - the remplementation of hasOwnProperty() did not affect the Object
}
```

```js
let person = Object.create(null);
person.age = 35;
if (Object.hasOwn(person, 'age')) {
  console.log(person.age); // true - works regardless of how the object was created
}
```

More about `Object.hasOwn` can be found here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn

Browser compatibility - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn#browser_compatibility

Checking if the specified property exists on the object itself or up in the prototype chain could be verified via the `in` operator as other answers suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Since question was regarding clunkiness of property checking, and one regular usecase for that being validation of function argument options objects, thought I'd mention a library-free short way of testing existence of multiple properties.
Disclaimer: It does require ECMAScript 5 (but IMO anyone still using IE8 deserves a broken web).

```
function f(opts) {
  if(!["req1","req2"].every(opts.hasOwnProperty, opts)) {
      throw new Error("IllegalArgumentException");
  }
  alert("ok");
}
f({req1: 123});  // error
f({req1: 123, req2: 456});  // ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other examples in this thread, this implementation only asserts that object has a property for which we are checking.

```
const hasOwnProperty = <X extends {}, Y extends PropertyKey>(
  object: X,
  property: Y
): object is Record<Y, unknown> & X => {
  return object.hasOwnProperty(property);
};
```

Here is an example of it being used to identify a branch that has the desired property.

```
const hasOwnProperty = <X extends {}, Y extends PropertyKey>(
  object: X,
  property: Y
): object is Record<Y, unknown> & X => {
  return object.hasOwnProperty(property);
};

type PaidProjectFeeType = 'FIXED_PRICE' | 'RATE' | '%future added value';

const PAID_PROJECT_FEE_TYPE_LABELS: Record<
  'FIXED_PRICE' | 'RATE',
  string
> = {
  FIXED_PRICE: 'Fixed Price',
  RATE: 'Rate',
};

export const getPaidProjectFeeTypeLabel = (
  feeType: PaidProjectFeeType
): string => {
  if (hasOwnProperty(PAID_PROJECT_FEE_TYPE_LABELS, feeType)) {
    PAID_PROJECT_FEE_TYPE_LABELS[feeType];
  }

  throw new Error('test');
};
```

https://tsplay.dev/m0LBOm

Annoyingly, the catch is that now `PAID_PROJECT_FEE_TYPE_LABELS` is assumed to be:

```
Record<PaidProjectFeeType, unknown> & Record<"FIXED_PRICE" | "RATE", string>
```

i.e. You cannot return the result because a possible value of `X[Y]` is `unknown`. This is useful when you need to assert that object has a desired property, but you will need to add further assertions to ensure that the result is what you intend.

There is a better way, though.

We will need two utilities:

```
export const keys = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  object: T
): Array<keyof T> => {
  return Object.keys(object);
};
```

`keys` gives us a typed array of object property names.

```
export const includes = <C extends M, M>(
  collection: readonly C[],
  member: M
): member is C => {
  return collection.includes(member as C);
};
```

`includes` allows to assert that a property is a member of a read-only array. You can read more about includes in this [blog post](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-array-includes/).

```
export const keys = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  object: T
): Array<keyof T> => {
  return Object.keys(object);
};

export const includes = <C extends M, M>(
  collection: readonly C[],
  member: M
): member is C => {
  return collection.includes(member as C);
};

type PaidProjectFeeType = 'FIXED_PRICE' | 'RATE' | '%future added value';

const PAID_PROJECT_FEE_TYPE_LABELS: Record<
  'FIXED_PRICE' | 'RATE',
  string
> = {
  FIXED_PRICE: 'Fixed Price',
  RATE: 'Rate',
};

export const getPaidProjectFeeTypeLabel = (
  feeType: PaidProjectFeeType
): string => {
  if (includes(keys(PAID_PROJECT_FEE_TYPE_LABELS), feeType)) {
    return PAID_PROJECT_FEE_TYPE_LABELS[feeType];
  }

  throw new Error('test');
};
```

https://tsplay.dev/N7gLDN

In short, this approach allows us to narrow down `feeType` value to the values present in `keys(PAID_PROJECT_FEE_TYPE_LABELS)`, which then allows us to access the property value.

This approach works the best, with a caveat that technically `keys` implementation is not run-time safe. There is (mostly theoretical) scenario where values returned runtime are different than those inferred using tsc.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! Would be nice with an explanation of your answer and not just code.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [{"b":1,"c":100},{"a":1,"b":1,"c":150},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":100},{"a":2,"b":1,"c":13}]

const result = data.reduce((r, e)  => {
  r['a'] += (e['a'] ? e['a'] : 0)
    r['d'] += (e['b'] ? e['b'] : 0)
  r['c'] += (e['c'] ? e['c'] : 0)

  return r
}, {'a':0, 'd':0, 'c':0})

console.log(result)
`result` { a: 4, d: 5, c: 363 }
```

Answer (score -3):

Why not simply:

```
if (typeof myObject.myProperty == "undefined") alert("myProperty is not defined!");
```

Or if you expect a specific type:

```
if (typeof myObject.myProperty != "string") alert("myProperty has wrong type or does not exist!");
```

Comment: Because its bad to read and not type strict. I must ask to you: why not simply `x.hasOwnProperty('y')`?