# How to execute statement in javascript if variable defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check a not defined variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript)
>   [Determining if a javascript object has a given property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894792/determining-if-a-javascript-object-has-a-given-property)

In my beforeSend function i have this

`$.myloader.show();`

But some scripts dont have that element so my this line gives me error

`$.myloader.show();` gives me error that $.myloader does not exists

How can i do something like

```
if($.myloader exists)
$.myloader.show();
```

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858181/how-to-check-a-not-defined-variable-in-javascript?rq=1 (and other links visible at the right...)

Comment: try {
      some_var.xxx.xxx.xxx
      x = 't';
   }catch(e){
      x = 'f';
   }
console.debug(x);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most generic and solid solution is :

```
if (typeof $.myloader != 'undefined') {
```

If you're sure your variable can't hold anything else than a function or undefined, you might use

```
if ($.myloader) {
```

But do this only when you're sure of the possible values because this test also match `false`,  `0` and `''`.

Comment: It does not match `'0'`, `[]`, etc, and the test is reversed.

Comment: That's something different. `if('0')` *will* execute.

Comment: @pimvdb You're right, I got a little carried over...

Comment: No problem :). I still think the test is reversed, though.

Comment: @pimvdb I need a second coffee I think... I should not come on SO before coding...

Answer (score 1):

If you want it short, you can also do it like this:

```
$.myloader && $.myloader.show();
```

The first operand (before the &&) is called a *guard*. However some people argue that this is not readable and safe enough, so you might want to use the `if (typeof ...)` solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as folllow...

```
if(typeof $.myloader != 'undefined')
{    // your code here.  };
```

Comment: You most certainly want `!==`, not `!=`

Comment: @nfechner that doesn't seem needed : [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) always return a string.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined values are 'falsey', and evaluate to false in an if statement, so all you need is:

```
if( $.myloader )
    $.myloader.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that jQuery (`$`) is an object:

```
if ($.hasOwnProperty('myloader'))
{
    //should work
    //try: $.hasOwnProperty('fn'), it'll return true, too
}
```

if the `myloader` object isn't directly bound to the jQuery object, but via one of its prototypes:

```
if ('myloader' in $)
{
    //works, like:
    if ('hasOwnProperty' in $)
    {//is true, but it's not a property/method of the object itself:
        console.log($.hasOwnProperty('hasOwnProperty'));//logs false
    }
}
```

You can check for the methods you want to use in the same way:

```
if ('myloader' in $ && 'show' in $.myloader)
{
    $.myloader.show();
}
```

Comment: `$` is actually a function, but of course also inherits from `Object`... in the end, everything does (apart from `Object.create(null)`), so it should not really matter what `$` is.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, it's a function, but functions are first class objects. Tomato - tomato, really

Answer (score 0):

You can do this even more shortly:

```
$.myloader.show() ? console.log('yep') : console.log('nope');
```

Or:

```
$.myloader.show() || console.log('fail');
```