# handle undefined properties before they 'fail'

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I would like to handle undefined properties and/or identifiers on my object before they fail/return undefined if that is possible.

Is there a neat way to capture the access to a non-defined property and handle it without using try/catch?

```
var myObj = {
    myVar : 10,
    myFunc : function(){console.log('foo')
}

myObj.myVar;
myObj.myFunc();

var x = "myFunc";
myObj[x];
x = "myOtherFunc";
// Handle this in an eventhandler or similar before it fails!?!?
myObj[x];
```

I can not alter the calling code from my position. I can only change the code inside myObj, since its a module used by others.

Comment: What fails exactly? You can get an undefined properties from an object without error -- `console.log({}.foo) // undefined`. If you need to work with the value, you can see if it exists first: `if (x in myObj) myObj[x]...` [Determining if a javascript object has a given property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894792/determining-if-a-javascript-object-has-a-given-property).

Comment: Nope, there's nothing like [`__call`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) in javascript, keep track of what you have and you should be fine.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Well, i am in a position where i cannot alter the code outside myObj and therefore i cannot check if x exist in myObj before i call it.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  myObj.myOtherFunc();
} catch() {

}

myObj.myOtherFunc() || ""; //default value;

myObj.myOtherFunc() || myObj.myDefinedFunc(); //default value;

if (var t = myObj.myOtherFunc())
  // something
else
  // something else
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, this wont work for me since i can not change the calling code. I can only change the code inside myObj

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(myObj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
    myObj[x];
}
```

Comment: Edited question to explain why your answer wont work for my case. Fair answer to solve to problem in general though.