# How to determine if an element has NO data-attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a sort of a niche case here.

So I'm building out a sidebar tool to utilize for quick note-taking, and I'm running into a problem without setting hundreds of `data-attr`s.

Currently, I have a dropdown menu that displays content that contains a specific `data-attr` based on the selection and hides the rest. The problem I'm encountering is I also want it to display all items that do *not* contain *any* `data-attr`s.

Is there a simple way to check if an item has **no** `HTML` defined `data` sets?

**HTML:**

```
<select id="ouSelect">
  <option></option>
  <option data-ou="aiv">AIV ***</option>    
  <option data-ou="appstore">Appstore ***</option>
  <option data-ou="firetv">Fire TV ***</option>
  <option data-ou="kindle">Kindle ***</option>
</select>

<ul id="stuffs">
  <li data-kindle="true">Kindle</li>
  <li>Generic</li>
  <li data-aiv="true">AIV</li>
  <li>Generic</li>
  <li data-firetv="true">FireTV</li>
  <li>Generic</li>
  <li data-appstore="true">Appstore</li>
  <li>Generic</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  var ou = "";
  $('#ouSelect').change(function() {
    ou = $('#ouSelect option:selected').data('ou');
    ouSelected(ou);
  });
  function ouSelected(which){
    $('li').each(function(){
      if($(this).data(which) === undefined){
        $(this).hide();
      } else {
        $(this).show();
      }
    })
  }
});
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyqoK

As you can see, all of the generic sets disappear when an option is selected. Ideally I'd want the items with `data-kindle` to display as well as items with **no** `data-attr`s at all.

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you found your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894792/determining-if-a-javascript-object-has-a-given-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your check to this:

```
if($(this).data(which) === undefined && Object.keys($(this).data()).length > 0)
```

Comment: ^ Perfect :-) Thank you! Always love a quick response.

Comment: Juvian - I looked you up and you're spamming downvotes. I will not accept your answer unless you correct that, because all of the answers work technically.

Comment: @NicholasHazel: How would you determine that?

Comment: @NicholasHazel He did not downvote once today, his -2 rep is because his answer got downvoted aswell.

Comment: @NicholasHazel as explained, haven´t made a single downvote today, just had my answer downvoted as well and that gives -2 rep as well

Comment: @NicholasHazel What makes you think downvoting is a bad thing?

Comment: It's not. But spamming them is.

Answer (score 0):

Given support for the `dataset` property, it’s as easy as:

```
Object.keys(element.dataset).length === 0
```

That’s not really appropriate, though. `data-*` attributes aren’t meant to interfere with each other, and they shouldn’t have dynamic names. How about identifying categories in a simpler way?

```
<li data-category="appstore">Appstore</li>
```

(Not given support for the `dataset` property, you can use

```
function hasDataAttributes(element) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.attributes.length; i++) {
        var name = element.attributes[i].name;

        if (name.substring(0, 5) === 'data-') {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

.)

Comment: ^ Totally reasonable. I will end up doing that anyway :-) Regarding your original line, it seemed to only pull one li item.

Comment: @NicholasHazel: How did you use it?

Comment: `if($(this).data(which) === undefined || $(this).keys(element.dataset).length ===0){`

Comment: @NicholasHazel: `Object.keys(this.dataset).length`. Literally “Object”.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FCicn - Looks broken still. I already have my answer though :-) Thank you a ton for the help. None of these downvotes are from me btw.

Comment: @NicholasHazel: `this`, not `element`.