# Meteor Check if Template Exists

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have Meteor application that uses Iron-Router in which the rendered screen is dynamic based on the URL.
I have two parameters from the URL, `station` and `screen`.

In the routing code:
`this.render(stationParam+screenParam, {to: 'content'});`

However, I want to be able to check if the template `stationParam+screenParam` exists.

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe try to test it using `!this.Data()`. I think it is the testing condition used by the pageNotFound redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All templates are stored as a field of a global object, `Template`. The question then is: How to check if this global object has a given field?

You have multiple ways to do it. My personal favourite using [`underscore`](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
if (_.has(Template, stationParam + screenParam)) { /* ... */ }
```

Underscore is included in Meteor. If you want to use it in a package, don't forget the `api.use('underscore')` in your `describe` callback.

See also: [Determining if a javascript object has a given property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894792/determining-if-a-javascript-object-has-a-given-property)