# Typescript check if property in object in typesafe way

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, undefined, typeguards

The code

```
const obj = {};
if ('a' in obj) console.log(42);
```

Is not typescript (no error). I see why that could be. Additionally, in TS 2.8.1 "in" serves as type guard.

But nevertheless, is there an way to check if property exists, but error out if the property is not defined in the interface of obj?

```
interface Obj{
   a: any;
}
```

I'm not talking about checking for undefined...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine whether an object has a given property in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894792/how-to-determine-whether-an-object-has-a-given-property-in-javascript)

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You don't get an error because you use a string to check if the property exists.

You will get the error this way:

```
interface Obj{
   a: any;
}

const obj: Obj = { a: "test" };

if (obj.b)          // this is not allowed
if ("b" in obj)     // no error because you use string
```

If you want type checking to work for string properties you could add [index signatures using this example](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures)

Comment: But "if (obj.b)" also disallows undefined. There is a difference between property not existing and it being undefined. I JUST want to check if the property exists in a typesafe way.

Comment: The type system already defines if the property exists or not, so there is no need to check it yourself. Type guards are used when an object can be of multiple types, such as: `const obj: Thing | OtherThing`.

Comment: No if i have an interface { a?: any; }, I do not know if the property exists. And if I get an object from a server I don't control (e.g.), I never know what property exists. I just want to discriminate in a typesafe way between actual undefined or property not existing at all!

Comment: If you don't know what your JSON data looks like, you can use `console.log(o.hasOwnProperty("a"))` to see if a property exists at all. If it exists but it's undefined, then it will still return true.

Comment: still is not a typesafe check but your answer is stell the best because only one. and i can always write a function to do a typesafe "in" check myself (with typescript keyof syntax)

Comment: I should add an example of index signatures to get type safety with `obj[“test”]`

Comment: Very useful to verify interfaces! https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard#in

Answer (score 12):

The following `handle` function checks hypothetical server response typesafe-way:

```
/**
 * A type guard. Checks if given object x has the key.
 */
const has = <K extends string>(
  key: K,
  x: object,
): x is { [key in K]: unknown } => (
  key in x
);

function handle(response: unknown) {
  if (
    typeof response !== 'object'
    || response == null
    || !has('items', response)
    || !has('meta', response)
  ) {
    // TODO: Paste a proper error handling here.
    throw new Error('Invalid response!');
  }

  console.log(response.items);
  console.log(response.meta);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=2#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). Function `has` should probably be kept in a separate utilities module.

Comment: This is not type-safe though. If you define `response: {'a': number}`, `has('items', response)` does not yield an expected compile-time error.

Comment: Erm... I've published the solution for cases when you're unable to control the type of arguments of the function `handle`. For example, this could be API endpoint handler -- everyone can accidentally send invalid data there. That's why `handle` accepts the argument of type `unknown` (which means "everything, I don't know what"). Type-safety here means that you're unable (in compile time) to use `response` without  checking its type. E.g. [here](https://cutt.ly/qdS5nvj) in line 24 `response.somethingElse` was used without type-check and TypeScript complains about that.

Comment: Oh, so you meant "type-safe" in a completely different way than I thought. Cool one, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 9):

You can implement your own wrapper function around hasOwnProperty that does type narrowing.

```
function hasOwnProperty<T, K extends PropertyKey>(
    obj: T,
    prop: K
): obj is T & Record<K, unknown> {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
}
```

I found this solution here:
[TypeScript type narrowing not working when looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67849097/typescript-type-narrowing-not-working-when-looping)

Usage:

```
const obj = {
    a: "what",
    b: "ever"
} as { a: string }

obj.b // Type error: Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: string; }'

if (hasOwnProperty(obj, "b")) {
    // obj is no longer { a: string } but is now
    // of type { a: string } & Record<"b", unknown>
    console.log(obj.b)
}
```

The limitation with this approach is that you only get a Record back with the single key added that you specified. This might be fine for some needs, but if you need a more general solution then I suggest a library like Zod which can validate a complex object and give you the full type: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod

Comment: I'm baffled that the built-in property checks don't already narrow types like this. I'm adding this to my default "include in all my TypeScript projects" code.

Comment: Can you explain what `obj is T & Record<K, unknown>` means please?

Comment: I keep getting `Type '<Whatever>' is not assignable to type 'never'` errors when I do `if (!has(o, p) { o[p] = x }` when using your signature instead of `const has = (obj: { [key: string]: any; }, prop: string) => {` which is what I had before. I have to keep doing `(o[p] as Whatever) = x`

Comment: Docs for [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), and the [record type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)