# TypeScript type narrowing not working when looping

Tags: typescript

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but I've been stuck on this one for a while.

Given the following predicate <sub>(I know it's not *technically* a predicate)</sub>:

```js
const hasProp = <K extends PropertyKey, T extends {}> (obj: T, prop: K): obj is T & Record<K, unknown> => {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```js
const coreProps = ['id', 'module', 'name', 'auth'] as const;
for (const prop of coreProps) {
  if (!hasProp(rawObject, prop)) {
    throw new Error(`Missing property '${prop}'`);
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't let me use e.g. `rawObject.id` afterwards. *If I manually unroll the loop, it works as expected.*

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a limitation of the TypeScript compiler?

---

I did come up with this alternative:

```js
const hasProps = <Ks extends PropertyKey[], T extends {}> (obj: T, ...props: Ks): obj is T & { [K in Ks[number]]: unknown } => {
  return props.every(prop => hasProp(obj, prop));
}
```

But I don't like this, because it doesn't return any information about which property is missing (if any).

Comment: *"But I don't like this, because it doesn't return any information about which property is missing..."* Couldn't it throw like your loop does?

Comment: Technically yes, but I have `hasProps` in a file of utilities and I'll almost certainly use it elsewhere. Ideally I'd like it to be isolated from that implementation detail.

Comment: It doesn't seem like an implementation detail to me, it seems like it's intrinsic to what the function does. But you could always make a companion function you use in the false case that tells you what's missing. Anyway, hope you find a solution you like.

Comment: You're right, that probably will be suitable for my use case. I guess now I'm just curious why lifting the loop out of the function causes the type checking to fail

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should use `assert` function for this purpose:

```js
const hasProp = <K extends PropertyKey, T>(obj: T, prop: K): obj is T & Record<K, unknown> => {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
}

const rawObject: any = {}

const coreProps = ['id', 'module', 'name', 'auth'] as const;

type Props = typeof coreProps;


function assert(value: unknown): asserts value is Record<Props[number], unknown> {
  for (const prop of coreProps) {
    if (!hasProp(rawObject, prop)) {
      throw new Error(`Missing property '${prop}'`);
    }
  }
}


assert(arg);// <---- assert function
arg.id // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgQwgBQE4gA4wLwwDwDSMApgB5TFgAmEMamxqUAngccwDQwAqAfABQgARgCsAXDy4Z0GCQQCUE4SJgBLWtxgAyGACVioVFUJcArmADWYEAHcwvHA4DeAKBgxUxKKdRgYAeVEDKAA6aRAoCOYMYhDECH87ehimZhDgBAAbTMFRKRl5AG4XAF8XF1BIWFQEG0CRYIl9Q2NoVFUwAHMuNo7Oh1wnMorwaBhDYmTaXABtAHJVKjmuOYBbECpTTOJlmDmwBFWdlYRTKDg5gF0YJHHRqGKXFhi6GWmYZ%20IQADM7zynHi5vuZgFBVOAbhAIIwoPwAG5ZUzECTmKy2MCKSHQpi0BGZJFqWjNEBGPBTGZgUyrISMS5mSzWOzONwwb4kmD8SpjcJYH5-SZveQwVzudyqX78ACE8WS-BqdSCoPymHkQpFovc53QNhgYGIOoAoqh0Kh%20AADACy6ggfRgPJhzD2ABInDySnMzUUWe4yj7SuURlVWSAQDgOQhUJ0JAgwMwhdhme4kNjYRHOkUAPQZ-AAWjzOaxMNZILB4BZaZCixgWZgIAspSAA)

[Assertion function examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHEEsDcFMDtQCkCG0UGUDGAnSAHAFwHIBnUAMwBtYAPSAI0iskIE8AaUV0LFRBrFApQAcwD24gCbcpsEYXHCpUgLAAoEKBwBXeIUgBbIVgAWsLAGtyi0G3E6cvaUNvoWUlISH3Hw0qQ6hkSQ4vCkAHQaGloAKuakQig4rmz4kHxUVGy8KFmwMigBsDgGYeQAFOJOkPDoePyEpACUwvBqmmCE5jnJQqSGeVSUelhl4aAA7qYZptookImgJTjV5PI42VPm8DFgvk71kCgMNORSYcSEoIOEZqA6%20KC20152Dsu0%20BaEUep7oAAci5nMZyJNWHMRBRRuNKNVQBdaqJnjNyA5ruIKKihAxxLQOADWGRcvlCsVSm0ZMTyGgFlQTjQppCMW1uMFqr9op1QAB1WDEFJicTI55KOQUWpCBxOcSTRDdByiUwRUDxRaIiwMlK0gEw%20BjUKIaazfyJUo2UxvbpCOj4HWkI2kmgdLTuHRCDWEXSwABcGjkWG1Qn1hrCZpKhAq7r9D3glngcvgzV9EYtoBjAG5uVpgZMpgKhToljw3HlIJ5vDjnmlpdj%20Mt4EEA1q%20s5wtdBmxBBhvciAPI4QFBQQ4VOkPvwFEAH1ATcMo%20z6iK5qj7G%20WJuKG7sF7eCng%20HC5KoAAvOfQAAiCf70SX5pLgG8yFq2vYPBEUAAZgiAHYuDazhyJQVBym0eRsI65B8IgxauAksAAuusDotiobjDYSiSqIjjSjo1yvNcgFYCCiyqhg4iEjy0wIO8OigKY4hwLKzHVkcjK4rAoH5gAtHRuSIIk8FeES1xWuQgi0fAySrJMBSUKshjCKAN6igi86jmKAIAFbFtcIiqVOfwaF2PaTqIh4jiUj48gAmh8MEPEsK6Rk66FGphW6WEIOHJI0sAoaAWIAgcNbfJaqw6MqrKhbUFArPJJFyFwFAInQKDBDQAKxG%20uAENcCZypa1poiMBpwhCWTaLAhCOIgKAAhpJ4Qoq%20HVvAAUyLYKAqGFgW2IB%20B%20cY3g4AC0DHNWJxMUkFLXIG2peEaxnqO54aGDoVAGPg2QVLQqb8JwdgHfAbCtAA3hooBpmutabrQZ4XpeTU4PeS7XS5pQVMhm45Oep5Xi9b3ctdKS1TgiAPQAVHYS4AL45mAACCc1ubCHnCEKjqnMink5d8EA6MkUikAC6WZX6yE8b5OAk58WCwJ%20Nq9BQ8VjNWJH6KswzUHKAI0YgPCcwYTb9aYkXKtWa3wCtWgAGJpbQGU7bAXByQJTmzauaPlRjtjSTgskAg2CBBIiSZBaxBjGP6-zqAtbacxOQUdf2FBy5AOATh7cBHqOpCpgAjKAs4AEwh9%20EcACwRwArDZDtCtL3CkP2KgVENOAZameiFfKKY3eQmcZSnoDB7OX5x0uichuj4aLAAQlxcoK44GfDTn8aJvnB1zUXw2l%20XoDhxX0c2XEpWkIxm0yFgbUXPK1am0pihBxHlezrH3KLGnUhVK77ue97MCwH7JQtEuYSwG7Hte4QPun1ZXvj2A6rgswww2ogc9EeYjZBCSfA4gAiMCZBOLw-VxBrwrtvUgTduKtxwPva%20h874PzPl7B8Ggr43yPvfE%20GDSAvzVKVDUIh7RGBPOGUg4hjBBWxIBeKXhcKoRujrMM4QiSIHxruPKn4fy-lAHxXwGtJTtCCm1Qw1RcQ5BSD1UUNoAQpBoEUIQiZvABz2ACUwhBCD4ADiAOQ0BTjiFEJEQwGRVg0IoL8EihhgDIVIHwwgwB%20CJlGMiHijjnE8S-DxX8wAgA)

[TS official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)

Hence, in order to make it work, you should wrap your loop into `assert function`. In this way, TS is able to infer the type of your object, otherwise it wont be able to do it because of mutable nature of objects.

Comment: I tried using `hasProp` in my code and it just caused issues and weird type errors I couldn't understand. Replacing it with `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` made those errors go away.

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy could you please provide me with a reproducible example ?

Comment: Here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcA8AVANIgaUQFMAPKYsAE3UQAUAnOAB2IagE8DiOA+ACgBQiRHABGAKwBciPMMTMmzGQUEBKGeImIYtbIgBkiAErEIcBlUwF84ANZg4AdzC9EAb3kNiUEAyQA8pJmUAB0inBQkRysoWjoAS6MLGycoRCoADaZ-Fr4EcxqANyCAL6CgqCQsAgKIOjIycw4McQC8loy7ogA2nY8MuhQDDBgAOYAujLYrT0TiKW48gWDw6NjSyIAblkgxNOt6h7yMMCI-ACE8bmS+UpqasciIlo9BfMAvL0TJSLlL5I3koJuF6sh+DtMntil4fH4kFoSuVKuBoPAkMwwU0AHIWAC2WRarHaAOkHl6-Q4qxG4ymslm80WyyU1PWm0QkL2B1YR08IlO5wuQQkIXCTCinFi8USYCaqQ46SyOTyCnujz5z1e70QXzmvwWHUB71BDQhu2IMJE3l8-lEkiRgiAA

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy `has` acts as a typeguard, it works flawless without negation, but with negation, TS is unable to infer `obj`, because there is no such thing as a `type negation` in typescript. Since you are mutatinh the object, you can consider this `Object.assign(obj, { [prop]: [] })`