# How to check custom key is present in array of object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object with this structure

```
[
  {
    "Apple": "fruit"
  },
  {
    "Orange": "fruit"
  },
  {
    "Cake": "sweet"
  }
]
```

How i can check Apple is present in this array of object using javascript

Comment: `[].find()` will help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether an object has a given property in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894792/how-to-determine-whether-an-object-has-a-given-property-in-javascript)

Comment: @Tân Not a dup, OP has an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and test with `in` or [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```js
let arr = [ { "Apple": "fruit" }, { "Orange": "fruit" }, { "Cake": "sweet" } ] 

console.log(arr.some(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('Apple')))
console.log(arr.some(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('Bannana')))
```

This will return `true` for the first condition that matches and `false` if none match.