# a shorter way to change some object values to uppercase

Tags: javascript, uppercase

I have a large object and need to change some values (**not all of them**) to upperCase

```
obj.state = obj.state.toUpperCase();
obj.city = obj.city.toUpperCase();
obj.street = obj.street.toUpperCase();
obj.title = obj.title.toUpperCase();
```

is there a shorter way, like this:

```
obj(state,city,street,title).toUpperCase();
```

Thanks

Comment: Would a loop be considered "shorter"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through all the keys of the object and do something like this:

```js
for (const k of Object.keys(obj)) {
  obj[k] = obj[k].toUpperCase()
}
```

If you only want to update some of the values, you can filter the keys:

```js
const keys = ['state', 'city', 'street', 'title']
for (const k of Object.keys(obj).filter((k) => keys.includes(k))) {
  obj[k] = obj[k].toUpperCase()
}
```

You can turn it into a function to make it reusable:

```js
function objToUpperCase(obj, keys) {
  for (const k of Object.keys(obj).filter((k) => keys.includes(k))) {
    obj[k] = obj[k].toUpperCase()
  }
  return obj
}
// to call:
objToUpperCase(obj, ['state', 'city', 'street', 'title'])
```

Comment: this will change all values, I need some of them only

Comment: Might want to check that [Object or its prototype has a property:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894803/14956277) `if ('toUpperCase' in obj[k])`.